# what use tensorflow estimator create multi-input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Sorry my English is poor =。=

I create a keras model and use `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` convert to estimator but the model is multi-input, what can I create Dataset feed the data?

Here is my model code：

```
model = VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=(182, 182 , 3))
y = model.output
y = keras.layers.Flatten()(y)
y = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(y)
y = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(y)
y = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)
model = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=y)

input_image = keras.layers.Input(shape=(182, 182, 3))
input_anchor = keras.layers.Input(shape=(182, 182, 3))
out_image = model(input_image)
out_anchor = model(input_anchor)

out = keras.layers.concatenate([out_image, out_anchor])
out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
img_model = keras.Model([input_image, input_anchor], out)

face_model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.CollectiveAllReduceStrategy(num_gpus_per_worker=0)
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir='/home/zjq/test/image_model.h5', train_distribute=distribution)

est_model = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=image_model, config=config)
```

Now, I have a input list, the shape is [(100000, 182, 182, 3), (100000, 182, 182, 3), (100000, 1)],how to define the input function return tf.data.DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, name input placeholders:

```
input_image = keras.layers.Input(shape=(182, 182, 3),name='image')
input_anchor = keras.layers.Input(shape=(182, 182, 3),name='anchor')
```

If your input data are `train_data` and shape is `[(100000, 182, 182, 3), (100000, 182, 182, 3), (100000, 1)]`, then do it:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 512
EPOCHS = 4

def input_fn(data, epochs, batch_size):
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'image':data[0],'anchor':data[1]}, data[2]))
    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    SHUFFLE_SIZE = 1000
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_SIZE).repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
    # Return the dataset.
    return dataset
est_model.train(lambda :input_fn(train_data,EPOCHS,BATCH_SIZE))
```

The parameters `BATCH_SIZE`,`EPOCHS` and `SHUFFLE_SIZE` can be adjusted according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem!