# How to use dataset_from_generator with pandas data (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

Initially I was using dataset_from_tensor_slices, but since the data is too large (exceeds the 2gb limit) I had to use dataset_from_generator.This is my input function, but i am getting this error :features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: "class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'".Prior to the change from tensor slices to generator, no errors were thrown (until the 2gb limit).both features and labels are pandas dataframes.

```
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):



features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                             
print(type(features))
print(type(targets))

def gen():
    for feature, target in (features, targets):
        yield feature, target
ds = Dataset.from_generator(gen,(tf.float32,tf.float32), (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None])))
ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)


if shuffle:
  ds = ds.shuffle(10000)



features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

return features, labels
```

Comment: There's a lot missing from your code. You can refer this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716629/what-use-tensorflow-estimator-create-multi-input/53718576#53718576